# finding a path in a 2 dimensional plain with obstacles

Tags: algorithm, math

I'm trying to solve a programming task I've been given and I don't have the slightest idea how to do it.

This is the problem:

> Skinny Pete is invited to a garden birthday party. He doesn’t really
>   like parties too much, but heard that the birthday cake is going to be
>   really amazing and he wouldn’t like to miss the chance to try it.
>
> There is only one little problem. There is a sprinkler system
>   installed in the garden and by knowing his friends, there is a high
>   chance of someone turning it on as a party prank. Pete likes cake, but
>   really hates getting wet. Luckily he found a sketch of the garden that
>   has the location of the sprinklers and how far each one can sprinkle
>   water.
>
> - The garden looks like a rectangle that is open on one side and has the house in the opposite side.
> - The cake is going to be in the house.
> - The other two sides have fences so one can not enter through there, and the house does not have a back entrance. Pete is interested to
>     know if it is possible to enter the garden and get to the house
>     without any risk of getting wet.
>
> For simplicity we can think that the map of the garden is in Cartesian
>   coordinate system.
>
> - The garden is a rectangle that has sides parallel to the axes and having its bottom left corner at the origin (0, 0).
> - The entrance to the garden is the left side and the the house is at the right side.
> - Sprinklers are represented as circles with a center and a radius. Stepping anywhere inside such a circle might get you wet.
> - For the purpose of this problem, and since Pete is so skinny, we can think of him as just a point travelling in the space, with real
>     numbers as coordinates.
>
> Input Specifications First line of the standard input contains two
>   space separated integers H and W, the height and the width of the
>   garden.
>
> Next line contains the number of sprinklers N. After that N lines
>   follow having three space separated integers each - Xi, Yi and Ri.
>   This a description of a sprinkler as a circle with center (Xi, Yi) and
>   radius Ri.
>
> 1 ≤ N ≤ 128
>
> 1 ≤ H, W ≤ 1024
>
> 0 ≤ Xi ≤ W
>
> 0 ≤ Yi ≤ H
>
> 1 ≤ Ri ≤ 1024
>
> Output Specifications
>
> Output a single line containing “CAKE” (without quotes) if it is
>   possible to get to the house without getting wet and “NO CAKE”(without
>   quotes) otherwise.

thanks in advance to helpers

Comment: What is this?, Contest question or Assignment?

Comment: it was a question in a contest but the contest has already finished

Comment: Can you add a link to the problem?

Comment: this is a link to a pdf of the problem: http://docdro.id/mT7vDh5
unfortunately the contest site is not online anymore

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you show no code and you only implicitly ask for help, I'll give a key idea and leave the mathematics and the implementation to  you.

Skinny Pete can get the cake without getting wet *unless* there is a chain of sprinkler circles between the bottom and the top of the garden. In other words, we can assume that Pete succeeds. But look through all the circles. We see if any circle intersects the bottom edge of the garden--that is easy mathematics. If there is none, Pete really succeeds. If there is, see if there is another circle that intersects that first one, then if there is another that intersects the second, etc. Finally, you see if the last circle in this chain intersects the top edge of the garden. If there is any such chain of intersecting circles that also intersects top and bottom of the garden, poor Pete goes hungry. (Note that just one circle that intersects both top and bottom would also frustrate Pete--consider that to be a chain of one.)

Here is a diagram of the second example in your contest PDF, where you can see there is no chain of spanning circles so Pete succeeds.

[image]

And here is a diagram of the third example, where Pete fails. Note that there is a chain of four circles on the left, colored blue, that spans the garden.

[image]

Given that idea, there is an obvious `O(N^2)` algorithm to find all pairs of intersecting circles and an `O(N)` algorithm to find the circles intersecting the top and bottom sides of the garden. You could use a path-finding algorithm from graph theory to solve your problem. Think of the top and bottom sides and your circles as nodes in the graph, with two nodes connected with an edge if they intersect. You then search for a path between the nodes representing the top and bottom sides.

Good luck on figuring the mathematics, algorithm, and code.